# ¿Cómo explicar el uso del subjuntivo en la frase "Contra la banca nunca juegue, y si te toca ese puesto porque lo echen a suertes, ..."?

Tags: subjuntivo, sintaxis

Imaginemos la situación siguiente: una persona explica a la otra las reglas de juego de naipes.

> *Contra la banca nunca juegue, y si te toca ese puesto **porque lo echen
>   a suertes**, empieza el juego con una apuesta lo más baja posible.*

Me cuesta explicar el uso del subjuntivo en esta oración. Si es una oración causal (en su forma afirmativa),  el verbo debería ir en el indicativo, ¿no? ¿O tal vez tenga cierto matiz condicional o hipotético y signifique presuposición o posibilidad/probabilidad?

Comment: ¿No debería ser "_Contra la banca nunca juegue**s**_" para que siempre sea un trato de "tu" y no una mezcla?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convengamos que lo correcto sería utilizar el indicativo en esa proposición adverbial de causa:

- Contra la banca nunca juegues, y si te **toca** ese puesto porque lo **echan** a suertes, empieza el juego con una apuesta lo más baja posible.

Observo que el modo de esa adverbial de causa, que está a su vez incluida dentro de una adverbial de condición, sería subjuntivo si, en lugar de ser de condicional, la proposición adverbial mayor fuera temporal:

- Contra la banca nunca juegues, y cuando te **toque** ese puesto porque lo **echen** a suertes, empieza el juego con una apuesta lo más baja posible.

Mi teoría -- debería, con más tiempo, investigarlo más a fondo, pero mi sentido común de hablante nativo en principio la confirmaría -- es que en la proposición causal en cuestión se usa subjuntivo (aunque lo normal sería indicativo) porque el hablante desea imprimirle el sentido futuro o probable que caracteriza a las temporales y que, por razones gramaticales, no se traduce en el uso del subjuntivo en las condicionales de tiempo presente.

Ambas adverbiales, la condicional "si te toca ese puesto" y la temporal "cuando te toque ese puesto", apuntan al futuro, pero con distintos modos. Mi impresión es que ese sentido futuro (más comúnmente expresado por el subjuntivo) se traslada **en forma excepcional** a la adverbial causal cuando ésta está embebida en la condicional.

De todos modos, resulta interesante observar cómo la causal adopta el modo de la adverbial que la contiene: indicativo/indicativo, o subjuntivo/subjuntivo. Estoy seguro de que existe alguna norma al respecto, y si así no fuera, pues creémosla.